# Determine latest received git tag

Tags: git, git-tag

I need to write an autoupdate script for our project. I have everything, except that I can't determine the name of the latest received tag. I tried with git describe, but it tells me the latest checked out tag. I don't need that of course, I have to get the next reachable tag to checkout. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0 branch_name
```

to retrieve the name of the latest tag searching back from the tip of the desired branch, rather than `HEAD` (the current checkout).

That is, if your auto-update script has fetched `origin master`, you can do

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0 origin/master
```

Note: `--abbrev=0` makes `describe` return only the tag name, without a sha1 at the end. `--tags` makes describe return the latest annotated or unannotated tag. See [git-describe(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html) for a full discussion of the possible options.

Comment: sorry, I completely forgot about this question somehow :( only one addition: first I need to do a `git fetch origin master` and then I can use `git describe --tags --abrev=0 origin/master` origin master without the slash wouldn't work the way I need.