# Need to checkout GIT Latest Tag using batch script

Tags: git, batch-file

I have to use one batch script which needs to checkout the latest label while running that script in windows command propmt.

Comment: @E.Coms The OP didn't ask for a script here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the latest tags, and then check out using that information (for bash/shell scripts).

```
git fetch --tags
git checkout $(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))
```

Additionally you can also follow this answer: [Git Checkout Latest Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414104/git-checkout-latest-tag)

Comment: Thank you Roshan... It worked well...